# Unity .NET - Using a project runs well, using its template messes dependencies up

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Long story short: I am trying to develop a mod for Enter the Gungeon and other devs gave *me* a [ZIP of a simple mod VS project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwfvnplpdzg4ldc/Example%20Item%20Mod.zip?dl=0) with all dependencies solved, ready to be compiled and idiot-proof. When I export the project as a template and create a new project using it, references are lost and the code won't compile.

**Using the original project:**

- Screenshot of the main code as given by those devs (no errors displayed):

[image: Screenshot of the origintal code, nothing changed]

- Screenshot of the references *folder* (everything working):

[image: Screenshot of the references section]

When I press the compile button it runs perfectly. I can edit whatever I want that the project runs and compiles as expected. However, I didn't want to use that concrete ZIP whenever I was going to develop a new mod.

**Where I use the template, problems start coming**

My idea was to export the project as a template and select the template when creating a new mod using the *new solution* option. However it looks like VS looses some files on the way...

- The project created from the template generates errors (this template is supposed to be a carbon copy of the original project, isn't it?):

[image: Screenshot of the original code when the project is created from the template]

- And the references section from the new project show a lotta warnings (also created from the template of the original project):

[image: Screenshot of the references now show a lot of warnings]

As you can see, if we create a project from the template that is based on the original project the libraries aren't defined and some references show warnings (although hovering on them doesn't show anything).

I've already tried to do some *cheating* by copying the `.vstemplate` file from the template to the original project (plus putting the files into a zip) and not even that way the problem is solved.

What would you do or think of?

Comment: Are those reference DLLs local in your new project? My guess is that on your machine, a new project would reference something from a static dev location based on the version of Unity the project is running. The zip you got may have been referencing the DLLs directly (even packaged with the template!). If you didn't move the referenced DLLs into your new project or rebind the reference to somewhere on your machine, you'll run into this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

^^.

Dependencies can be annoying, but generally that warning symbol around at each dependency means it cant find them.

So, you should edit the `csproj` file (right click the file named "prueba dependencias" and click "edit project file") then look for the `Reference` tags. Make sure the `HintPath` tags point to a file. If they don't, then you can do one of two things: Change the content of the tag to point to a real file or create a dummy file where the path points.

Alternatively, you can remove all the dependencies it cant find, right click "Referencias", then "Add reference" and all the ones you removed back.

That should (hopefully) fix your issues.

Comment: I think I got the problem. Given that you told me to do stuff with the csproj file, I decided to read a bit of it and to understand what it meant.

I noticed that, although I can put in that file the route of the DLLs, the folders are deleted when exported to a template (I put all of them in a lib folder, for example) and thus they won't be on the new project.

Is there any way to say "yo don't delete this" other than to write an absolute path to the DLLs from another folder?

Comment: I'm not sure. I generally try to point everything to my game install, thus avoiding the need for that all together.